# Need help implementing a listener for user input in my Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, listener

I managed to put this GUI together by adapting code from a book. I'm not sure how to implement listeners into this code since it is above my level, but I need them to make testing my program easier. I've looked through the posts on this site that are similar, however no one used the same code structure as me and I'm not sure how to implement the solutions on those posts.

So far I've tried using  `JCheckbox.addActionListener(this);` which is what the oracle website said. Where ever I place this statement I get a variety of errors and I'm not sure why.

```
package inputform;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Traitform extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

        JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
        JCheckBox eye1 = new JCheckBox("Brown");
        JCheckBox eye2 = new JCheckBox("Blue");
        JCheckBox eye3 = new JCheckBox("Green");
        JCheckBox eye4 = new JCheckBox("Hazel");

        JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
        JCheckBox hair1 = new JCheckBox("Brown");
        JCheckBox hair2 = new JCheckBox("Blonde");
        JCheckBox hair3 = new JCheckBox("Ginger");
        JCheckBox hair4 = new JCheckBox("Black");

        JPanel row3 = new JPanel();
        JCheckBox eye5 = new JCheckBox("Brown");
        JCheckBox eye6 = new JCheckBox("Blue");
        JCheckBox eye7 = new JCheckBox("Green");
        JCheckBox eye8 = new JCheckBox("Hazel");

        JPanel row4 = new JPanel();
        JCheckBox hair5 = new JCheckBox("Brown");
        JCheckBox hair6 = new JCheckBox("Blonde");
        JCheckBox hair7 = new JCheckBox("Ginger");
        JCheckBox hair8 = new JCheckBox("Black"); 


        public Traitform () {
            super("Parent Trait Form");
            setSize(1000, 1000);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(0,1);
            setLayout(layout);

            row1.add(eye1);
            row1.add(eye2);
            row1.add(eye3);
            row1.add(eye4);

            row3.add(eye5);
            row3.add(eye6);
            row3.add(eye7);
            row3.add(eye8);

            row2.add(hair1);
            row2.add(hair2);
            row2.add(hair3);
            row2.add(hair4);

            row4.add(hair5);
            row4.add(hair6);
            row4.add(hair7);
            row4.add(hair8);


            add(row1);
            add(row2);
            add(row3);
            add(row4);


            setVisible(true);
        }

    private static void setLookAndFeel() {
        try{
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
                } catch (Exception exc){

            }
    }
        public static void main(String[] arguments){
            Traitform.setLookAndFeel();
            Traitform frame = new Traitform();

        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionListener e){
            System.out.println("action");
        }
}
```

I need this program to take the user input from the check boxes so that it can be used in another part of my program in a separate package. When I run the current code I get the error uncompilable program.

Comment: Looks like a use case for a preferences file, maybe even a database. You need to persist those values somewhere in order to `setLookAndFeel` at the program start (`main`).

Comment: This is the code from oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html ```public AL(String title) {

                super(title);
                setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                addWindowListener(this);
                b = new Button("Click me");
                add(b);
                add(text);
                b.addActionListener(this);```  It seems as though I just need to implement this into my existing code.

Comment: FYI you don't need the ButtonGroups, they are used for groups of radio buttons which you are not using.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly wrong:

```
JCheckbox.addActionListener(this);
```

addActionListener is not a static method. Also you probably want to do different things when different checkboxes are checked.

So you should do something like this:

```
hair5.addActionListener(() -> {System.out.println("hair5 clicked")});
```

You can also add single action listener for all checkboxes. For example put all your checkboxes in a list then do something like:

```
ActionListener myActionListener = () -> {System.out.println("my action listener")}
for (checkbox: checkboxList) {
    checkbox.addActionListener(myActionListener);
}
```

Comment: So rather than ```{System.out.println("hair5 clicked")}``` can I assign a variable an integer value, and then import that integer value into a different package? For example ```{int haircolor = 4 }``` ?

Comment: Yes you can execute any java code in the listener. It is like any other method call.

Comment: I tried your first line of code, for some reason I get an error saying ";" expected and "incompatible parameter types in lambda expression."

Answer (score 0):

The argument of `addActionListener()` method is an `ActionListner`  (see [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener))).
So too use `eye1.addActionListener(this);` (for example)  `this` need to be an `ActionListner`.  [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) is an interface, which means `this` `this` needs to implement `ActionListener`.
`this` , in your case is `traitform` class (which should be `Traitform` see [Java naming conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions)) :

After changing the class definition to

`public class Traitform extends JFrame implements ActionListener{`

You need to add the implementation. In this case it is one method:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // what ever you write here is invoked when action listener is used.
    System.out.println("Action listener fired !");
}
```

Following the example above (`eye1.addActionListener(this);`), the `actionPerformed` method is invoked when `eye1` fires an `ActionEvent`.

Comment: I just updated my code attempting to implement what you have provided. Adding implements JFrame gives me an error saying Traitform is not abstract. @Override gives me an error "does not implement method from a supertype"

Comment: `actionPerformed` expects an `ActionEvent` argument. Change `actionPerformed(ActionListener e)`  to  `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`in your code.